# How to import this demo into eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to see how this swipeview works by trying to load up the demo.

[viewswiper](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper)

However every time I try to import it into eclipse as an existing project it tells me "No project are found to import"

I am not that familiar with eclipse so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it may be a library, if it is you will have to make it not a library, just a thought though and don't have eclipse on this computer to verify.  you could alternatively create a project and then just put those files in the new project

Comment: I think it is a library. I guess if I make a project I have to make the same .com file package?

Comment: it would help so you do not break anything the developer may have hard coded the package reference into.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have any eclipse files in the repo - In order to turn it into an Eclipse project, create a new Android project, and use the radio buttons in the first screen to select "From Existing Source".

Comment: Ok I did that(I selected from the demo folder level). Yet when I try to run it it dies in the emulator just says it stopped unexpectantly yet gives me no error information.

Comment: Update:  It's a library project, so you can't run it by itself.  The readme of that git project here:  https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper/blob/master/README.markdown  directs you on how to use the tool in that library in your own project.